# How to get all the data inside some specific character in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some strings separated with comma. Those value I need to get in an array. Which I am able to do. For getting this I had done this.

```
var productArray = $("#service").data('product').split(',');
```

And those data are showing properly in `productArray` variable. Those data format are like this.

```
["[44]Medicine 2", "[63]Test Sam "]
```

Now I need to get those number which is inside this character `[]`. For instance I need to get `44` and `63` as per above data given.
I had done nothing for this part as I am not getting any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert your existing array.

Here's an example using `.split` on `[` and `]` to break into parts.  Another viable solution would be to use a regex.

```js
// from #service.data()
var data = "[44]Medicine 2,[63]Test Sam";

var array = data.split(",");

var ids = array.map(s => s.split("]")[0].split("[")[1]);
console.log(ids)

var id_name = array.map((s) => {
    return { id : s.split("]")[0].split("[")[1], name : s.split("]")[1] };
});
console.log(id_name)
```

---

As an alternative, if you can change how the `data-` attribute is generated, you can store (valid) json directly in the html then jquery's `.data()` will give you an object so there's no additional parsing required:

```js
var data = $("#data").data("data");

console.log(data.length, data[0].id, data[0].name);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='data' data-data='[{"id":"1","name":"test"},{"id":"2","name":"2nd"}]'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use RegEx for that: `/\[(.*)\]/`

```js
let res = ["[44]Medicine 2", "[63]Test Sam "].map(e => Number(e.match(/\[(.*)\]/).pop()));
console.log(res);
```

Or as one-step solution with your code:

```js
var productArray = $("#service")
    .data('product')
    .split(',')
    .map(e => Number(e.match(/\[(.*)\]/).pop()));
```

**Note**: I also implicitly casted to `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression:

```js
//instead of splitting the string:
console.log("[44]Medicine 2,[63]Test Sam ".match(/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/g));
```